# Resetting a simple Tkinter game(Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I tried to make a simple game using Tkinter. Basically you click some buttons and your current score is shown until you eventual win or lose.
Resetting the game when you eventually win/lose is where I got stuck.

```
class Game(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.food_count = 5
        self.age_count = 14
        self.player()

    def player(self):
        'My buttons and score'

    def score_checker(self):
        'Checks score, removes buttons and creates a reset button if win/lose'

    def reset_game(self):
        root.quit()
        Game(root)
        root.mainloop()

root = Tk()
root.title('Game')
root.geometry('400x200')
app = Game(root)
root.mainloop()
```

With this code I just get another another 'player' under the reset button. What I want to happen is to get a new session of the game as if I started the game for the first time.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing all the code, but one thing you could do is move everything out of the `__init__` method except the call to the super constructor and put it in the `reset_game` method. Then call `reset_game` in `__init__` and also whenever you want to restart the game. You probably shouldn't be trying to stop and restart the mainloop.

Comment: I was about to make the same suggestion.  Give it  a try.